# Add background picture to forms listview control 6.0 from excel sheet shape

Tags: excel, vba, image, listview, shapes

Is there a way to programmatically add a background picture to a listview control 6.0 placed on a worksheet, from within another excel worksheet cell shape (picture)?

I tried:

`Listview1.Picture = LoadPicture(Sheet2.Shapes("Picture 1"))`

I also tried:

`Listview1.Picture = Sheet2.Shapes("Picture 1")`

Comment: You would need to convert the Shape object to a Bitmap object. It doesn't automatically convert a shape to a bitmap for you.

Comment: @braX how to do it?